# SobiPro - Fatal error while submitting form in Joomla 3.7.2

Tags: php, joomla, fatal-error, sobipro

I have a customer who's using the plugin SobiPro to provide a directory where his users can submit work orders, and his customers can then bid on them. He recently had his Joomla installation updated, which then broke his SobiPro setup.

i have updated sobipro to the latest version, and running the compatibility check seems that everything is fine. However, when i try to submit a form, i get this error:
Fatal error: Call to a member function data() on null in (Joomla root)/components/com_sobipro/lib/cms/joomla_common/base/lang.php on line 366

anyone familiar with sobipro, who knows this error?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that after a thorough search in the database, i noticed that somehow most of the primary keys of each table was missing, so i exported all sobipro tables, and edited each table definition with primary key and auto increments where it was missing. Furthermore i cleaned all duplicates, and after that it was working. How the database missed the primary keys, i do not know though. maybe as a consequence of a faulty joomla upgrade.